# Which local database should be used for C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, sql-server

Which local database should be used for C# Windows applications?

I am very confused about Localdb, SQL Server Express and SQL Server Compact.

And install on client Machine.

Comment: There is another option : SQLite, file based database without any installation.

Answer (score 2):

- **SQL Server Express** is the currently favored option by Microsoft. It's a full database engine, but it must be (separately) installed on the client's PC, and it starts up as a Windows service in the background.
- **SQL Server LocalDB** is a **developer-oriented** special version of SQL Server Express, with the same feature set, and it, too, must be installed. Other than SQL Server Express, it doesn't start up as a Windows service in the background, but it gets fired up when your application starts, and terminates when your application finishes its work.
- **SQL Server Compact Edition** is a very different beast - uses `.sdf` files, is a **single-user, embedded** database, meaning you just need to include a few `*.dll` in your project, no separate installation needed. It's limited in its features, and it's no longer developed any further by Microsoft and will eventually go away

If you absolutely must have a "no-install" approach, you'll need to investigate other options, like SQLite or others.